# Include woocommerce custom field value in front-end search result

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, search

currently the search result only showing all the woocommerce default product field (product title, category, tag, .etc).

I've add a new custom field inside the woocommerce product using this code inside functions.php

```
/** Add Sub-Title option in Woocommerce */

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'my_custom_field' );

function my_custom_field() {

woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
array( 
    'id'          => '_subtitle', 
    'label'       => __( 'Reference', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => 'Reference code',
    'description' => __( 'Enter the reference code', 'woocommerce' ) 
)
);

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'my_custom_field_save' );

function my_custom_field_save( $post_id ){  

$subtitle = $_POST['_subtitle'];
if( !empty( $subtitle ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_subtitle', esc_attr( $subtitle ) );

}
```

**How can I include this custom field value in the search result?** I've tried google for it, but no any significant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify WooCommerce search query.

1. Hook into this action: `do_action( 'woocommerce_product_query',  $query,  $instance );`
2. Detect if it is a search query
3. Add your `_subtitle` meta

Something like this (not tested):

```
if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        array(
            'key' => '_subtitle',
            'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ));
};
```

Comment: function custom_search_query( $query ) {
 if ( $query->is_search ) {
   $query->set('meta_query', array(
     array(
       'key' => '_subtitle',
       'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
       'compare' => 'LIKE'
     )
   ));
 };
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_search_query');

Not working though.. :/

Comment: @NazrinNoorzan what part of it is not working? Did you try at least to figure it out? if yes what did you try.